# Angular - select an input field then click a separate button for increment

Tags: angular, button, angular-material, increment, input-field

just trying to do a function. At the moment i have a material table with a number of input fields and I am trying to do a function that is when I choose/selected an input field, i can do increment in that specific field with a separate '+' button.

At the moment, the problem i have is i do not know how i can keep a selected input field focus and let the function know which input field i have selected when i click the '+' button (at the moment i can only hardcode a parameter, want to make it dynamic)

would like to get some idea how i can do it? Thank you so much. I have a link with what i have at the moment
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-jmexkx?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

html file

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource">
  <ng-container [matColumnDef]="col.key" *ngFor="let col of columnsSchema">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>
      {{ col?.label }}
    </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
      <mat-form-field>
        <input [type]="col?.type" matInput [(ngModel)]="element[col.key]" />
      </mat-form-field>
    </td>
  </ng-container>
  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns"></tr>
</table>
<button mat-button type="button" (click)="increment('ED')">+</button> // **how can i make the parameter dynamic**
<button mat-button>-</button>
</div>
```

ts file

````
export interface SpecimenType {
  SE: string;
  ED: string;
  ES: string;
  GL: string;
  CI: string;
  HE: string;
  U: string;
  F: string;
  BF: string;
  SP: string;
  CS: string;
  T: string;
  P: string;
  SW: string;
  O: string;
}
const COLUMNS_SCHEMA = [
  {
    key: 'SE',
    type: 'number',
    label: 'SE'
  },
  {
    key: 'ED',
    type: 'number',
    label: 'ED'
  },
  {
    key: 'ES',
    type: 'number',
    label: 'ES'
  },
  {
    key: 'GL',
    type: 'number',
    label: 'GL'
  },
  {
    key: 'CI',
    type: 'number',
    label: 'CI'
  },
  {
    key: 'HE',
    type: 'number',
    label: 'HE'
  },
  {
    key: 'U',
    type: 'number',
    label: 'U'
  },
  {
    key: 'F',
    type: 'number',
    label: 'F'
  },
  {
    key: 'BF',
    type: 'number',
    label: 'BF'
  },
  {
    key: 'SP',
    type: 'number',
    label: 'SP'
  },
  {
    key: 'CS',
    type: 'number',
    label: 'CS'
  },
  {
    key: 'T',
    type: 'number',
    label: 'T'
  },
  {
    key: 'P',
    type: 'number',
    label: 'P'
  },
  {
    key: 'SW',
    type: 'number',
    label: 'SW'
  },
  {
    key: 'O',
    type: 'number',
    label: 'O'
  }
];

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit  {
  name = 'Angular ' + VERSION.major;
  constructor() {}

  columnsSchema: any = COLUMNS_SCHEMA;

  

  
  displayedColumns: string[] = COLUMNS_SCHEMA.map(col => col.key);
  dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<any>();
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.dataSource.data = [{ SE: 0, ED: 0, ES: 0, GL: 0, CI: 0, HE: 0, U: 0, F: 0, BF: 0, SP: 0, CS: 0, T: 0, P: 0, SW: 0, O: 0 }];
  }

  click() {
    console.log(this.dataSource.data);
  }

  increment(element: string) {
  
    this.dataSource.data[0][element]++;
    
    console.log(this.dataSource.data);
  }
}```


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aQPE8.png
````

Answer (score 0):

How about you add a button for each specimen? with that, you don't need to worry about which input has `focus` or anything, each column can be handled individually.

```html
<div class="overflow-auto">
  <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource">
    <ng-container [matColumnDef]="col.key" *ngFor="let col of columnsSchema">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>
        {{ col?.label }}
      </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element; let i = index">
        <mat-form-field>
          <input [type]="col?.type" matInput [(ngModel)]="element[col.key]" />
        </mat-form-field>
        <!-- Each cell has it's own + and - buttons -->
        <button mat-button type="button" (click)="onAdd(element, col.key)">+</button>
        <button mat-button (click)="onSubstract(element, col.key)">-</button>
      </td>
    </ng-container>
    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns"></tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

```js
onSubstract(element: SpecimenType, index: string): void {
  element[index] -= 1;
}

onAdd(element: SpecimenType, index: string): void {
   element[index] += 1;
}
```

Comment: thank you for the suggestion but this homework only allow for one set of button then use that for every fields